# Install Liferay as Windows 2012R2 service

Tags: installation, liferay

I am a newbie on Liferay and furthermore 100% Windows infrastructure knowledge based. I installed Liferay 6.2  on my Windows 2012R2 server together with Java jdk-8u5 version. All is running perfect as long as I am logged in as user on the Server via remotedesktop having open the tomcat startup.bat window.
What have I to do exactly to start Liferay and/or tomcat as service?

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Configuring liferay or tomcat to run as a service on a windows server doesn't differ that much.So in order to do that you have to add some files to the `LIFERAY_HOME\tomcat\bin` directory.

To get those files you have to download a full version of **64-bitWindows tomcat** from here :
http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi.
Extract the zip and go to the **bin** directory, copy `service.bat` , `tomcat7.exe` and `tomcat7w.exe` to this location : `LIFERAY_HOME\tomcat\bin`

1. Setting Up the service

Open the commad prompt (Make sure you have admin rights or run the command prompt as administrator),In Command Prompt go to  `LIFERAY_HOME\tomcat\bin` and Execute the following command

```
service.bat install tomcat7
```

This will install the tomcat6 service in windows. 
Now execute following commond to setup additional configuration for the service

```
tomcat7w.exe ES tomcat7.exe
```

[image]

2 . Extra configuration :

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Duser.timezone=GMT
-Djava.security.auth.login.config="%CATALINA_HOME%/conf/jaas.config"
-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
```

and make sure to provide enough memory for your service by setting the initial memory pool and the maximum one.
[image]

Comment: The file LIFERAY_HOME\tomcat\bin\setenv.bat contains the exact options you need to add for the extra configuration. In Liferay 6.2 CE GA2, for example, there is another option to add: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Answer (score 0):

Either go with Rafik Beldi's answer (quite an effort, wow) or just go to [tomcat's documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html) in case you're still missing some information

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete what was in Java Options completely or it wouldn't start: and then I entered:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Duser.timezone=America/New_York
-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

note that where I am: America/New_York allows for both EST and EDT