# Exception while configuring Tomcat (with Liferay) as 2012R2 service

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, service, liferay

I'm trying to configure Tomcat 7.0.56, with Liferay Portal 6.2 on it, as a 2012R2 service. Why am I emphasizing Liferay? Well, clean Tomcat server works perfectly as a service, but when i add Liferay Portal on it, service officially state is "running", but I can't access to Tomcat or stop the service so I must kill the process. I have opened service log and seen many errors (below the text, sorry for such a long log).

I tried on two different machines and I tried 2 installation options:

1) with clean Tomcat 7, locating liferay-portal.war into webapps folder and starting server through cmd with `startup` command and it works without problem. But if I install it as a service with line:
`service.bat install tomcat7` it returns many errors as I said earlier.

```
2014-11-06 09:10:24 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
stu 06, 2014 9:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.31 using APR version 1.4.8.
stu 06, 2014 9:10:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014)
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-80"]
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1238 ms 
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
stu 06, 2014 9:10:26 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\webs\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\liferay-    portal-6.2.war
stu 06, 2014 9:11:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
stu 06, 2014 9:11:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class       com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name    'com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path     resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean    'counterTransactionAdvice' while setting bean property 'methodInterceptor'; nested   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean  with name 'counterTransactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base- spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterTransactionManager' while setting  bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'counterTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]:  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor  argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path  resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested  exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(Bean DefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:227)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean     with name 'counterTransactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base- spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterTransactionManager' while setting  bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name  'counterTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]:  Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor  argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:  Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path  resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested  exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(Bean DefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean    with name 'counterTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(Bean DefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:630)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:441)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:982)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:878)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:484)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 38 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(Bean DefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2957)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1210)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1690)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.getMappedClass(PersistentClass.java:122)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.getGetter(PropertyFactory.java:191)
at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:67)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:135)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init> (AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init> (SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
at  org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)

stu 06, 2014 9:11:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
stu 06, 2014 9:11:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWARs
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of WAR files to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:818)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1613)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.util.CustomObjectInputStream.<init> (CustomObjectInputStream.java:56)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doLoad(StandardManager.java:244)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.load(StandardManager.java:202)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:489)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1083)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1879)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
... 4 more

stu 06, 2014 9:11:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\webs\apache-tomcat-   7.0.56\webapps\administracija
stu 06, 2014 9:11:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\webs\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\docs
stu 06, 2014 9:11:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectories
SEVERE: Error waiting for multi-thread deployment of directories to complete
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1613)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:330)
at    org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.authenticatorConfig(ContextConfig.java:493)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:900)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1247)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1897)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
... 4 more

stu 06, 2014 9:11:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\webs\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\examples
```

2) with Liferay+Tomcat7.0.42 bundle installation following instructions on similar topic, but it not helps: [Install Liferay as Windows 2012R2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119318/install-liferay-as-windows-2012r2-service). I've got new error that I googled for and it is connected with memory leaks, so I have temporarily increased MaxPermSize to `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m` but error still persist.

Log from Tomcat+Liferay bundle as a service:

```
2014-11-06 10:14:24 Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in    production environments was not found on the java.library.path: D:\Marko\LIFERAY\liferay- portal-tomcat-6.2\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-  7.0.42\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Wi     ndows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program     Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program    Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL    Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL    Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Network Monitor 3\;;.
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 654 ms
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
stu 06, 2014 10:14:25 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor D:\Marko\LIFERAY\liferay-portal-tomcat-    6.2\liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
stu 06, 2014 10:14:36 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->KQylLuQf] -    AdminTaskTimer" Exception in thread "C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken- >bp53QzD9]-AdminTaskTimer"
```

As Tomcat works alone perfect and without problem, I suppose it's something with Liferay's configuration that creates problems to Tomcat. But, as I said, both described options work perfect when I start them manually and problem is when I try to set them up to work as a service. Is it some Windows-based problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Now, I tried with Tomcat 8.0 (with Liferay) as a service, result - Tomcat started despite errors and is accessible on localhost, but Liferay hasn't been deployed. I put error log on link: http://www.codeshare.io/jB5jH, because I have passed allowed number of characters here.

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to add these lines to service.bat:

```
--JvmOptions "-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%;-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%;-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%CATALINA_HOME%\endorsed;-Djava.io.tmpdir=%CATALINA_BASE%\temp;-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager;-Djava.util.logging.config.file=%CATALINA_BASE%\conf\logging.properties;-Dfile.encoding=UTF8;-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false;-Duser.timezone=GMT;-Xmx1024m;-XX:MaxPermSize=512m" ^
--JvmMs 128 ^
--JvmMx 512
```