# How to run Liferay 7.1 as Windows service?

Tags: java, windows-services, liferay-dxp

I can run the portal fine when executing startup.bat. But when I tried to run it as service, following the steps in one of the answer in here: [Install Liferay as Windows 2012R2 service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119318/install-liferay-as-windows-2012r2-service) I receive java.lang.NullPointerException error
I used tomcat 9 instead of 7 (as in the link)

Java settings in tomcat9w.exe as per below

Java virtual machine:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Java Classpath:

```
D:\liferay-dxp-7.1.10-ga1\tomcat-9.0.6\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\liferay-dxp-7.1.10-ga1\tomcat-9.0.6\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
```

Java Options:

```
-Dcatalina.home=D:\liferay-dxp-7.1.10-ga1\tomcat-9.0.6
-Dcatalina.base=D:\liferay-dxp-7.1.10-ga1\tomcat-9.0.6
-Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\liferay-dxp-7.1.10-ga1\tomcat-9.0.6\temp
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=D:\liferay-dxp-7.1.10-ga1\tomcat-9.0.6\conf\logging.properties
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dorg.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES=false
-Duser.timezone=GMT
-Xms512m
-Xmx10240m
-XX:MaxPermSize=16384m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=16384m
```

Java 9 Options

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Initial memory pool: 10240 MB

Maximum memory pool: 24000 MB

Thread stack size: 512 KB

Entries from Liferay log file

```
2019-02-12 03:55:26.465 INFO  [main][HikariDataSource:95] HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-02-12 03:55:27.558 INFO  [main][HikariDataSource:107] HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-02-12 03:55:27.574 INFO  [main][DialectDetector:77] Determine dialect for Microsoft SQL Server 13.0
2019-02-12 03:55:28.011 INFO  [main][DialectDetector:155] Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
2019-02-12 03:55:31.621 INFO  [main][HikariDataSource:95] HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2019-02-12 03:55:31.652 INFO  [main][HikariDataSource:107] HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2019-02-12 03:55:32.574 INFO  [main][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.200.v20150831-0856 [0]
2019-02-12 03:55:32.761 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: d09fc806-7a2e-0019-1de8-abaf0d99730c][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.util.taglib_3.1.3 [2]
....<i truncated because too long>...
com.liferay.portal.social.activity.extender_1.0.1 [48]
2019-02-12 03:55:36.793 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: d09fc806-7a2e-0019-1de8-abaf0d99730c][DefaultLPKGDeployer:307] Start refreshing uninstalled orphan bundles
2019-02-12 03:55:36.793 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: d09fc806-7a2e-0019-1de8-abaf0d99730c][DefaultLPKGDeployer:315] Finished refreshing uninstalled orphan bundles
2019-02-12 03:55:38.308 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: d09fc806-7a2e-0019-1de8-abaf0d99730c][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED com.liferay.portal.target.platform.indexer.impl_1.0.1 [49]
2019-02-12 03:55:38.324 INFO  [Start Level: Equinox Container: d09fc806-7a2e-0019-1de8-abaf0d99730c][BundleStartStopLogger:35] STARTED org.apache.felix.dependencymanager.shell_3.2.0 [50]
2019-02-12 03:55:38.590 ERROR [main][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.DirectServletRegistryUtil.clearServlets(DirectServletRegistryUtil.java:27)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
2019-02-12 03:55:38.605 ERROR [main][PortalContextLoaderListener:114] java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.deploy.hot.HotDeployUtil.reset(HotDeployUtil.java:53)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:187)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:966)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1427)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1417)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:943)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
2019-02-12 03:55:38.605 ERROR [main][PortalBeanLocatorUtil:109] BeanLocator is null
```

Entries from tomcat stderr file are here: https://pastebin.com/TjgAjubq

Comment: Consider using 3rd party tools (or write you own) that can run any application as windows server and then run start.bat inside of your liferay usual installation using such tool (https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/) or just search for 'run windows app as a service'

Comment: Voting to close here for two reasons: (1) this is not programming related, thus [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stackoverflow, (2) You have opted to crosspost the question [without disclosing your crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site), and the question has been answered there

Comment: Any resolution to this?

Comment: @Olaf Kock I am getting the above error. Is there a resolution to the issue?

Comment: @clD you could ask the original poster where this question was crossposted. That's *exactly* the problem with crissposts, as it was answered apparently.